# Facebook Instant Articles for WP custom fields

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-instant-articles

I'm trying to include a custom field to the [Facebook Instant Articles for WP plugin for Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fb-instant-articles/).

I'm on wordpress version 4.4.2 and php-5.6.18.

The custom field is a field for pasting youtube iframe code, for embedding in articles.

Can anyone provide a hint or an example of how to include this custom field in the generated output of the plugin?

Comment: From the FAQ on that site: _“How do I customize the output for my site? There are a number of filters available in the plugin for modifying the output.”_ – so, have you looked at those already?

Comment: Yes, if I understand the code correctly, one of the the filters is ment to format youtube links, and it does, but not iframes. The problem in my case is that this works for links already included in the content, not for custom fields, which is my case. Somehow I must inject the custom field in the content before it is filtered. Probably I must also make a new filter for the iframes or change them with plain youtube links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally the solution was found in the plugin's support forum [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/include-custom-fields-in-feed?replies=7)

```
use Facebook\InstantArticles\Elements\Video;

add_action( 'instant_articles_after_transform_post', function ($ia_post) {
    $instant_article = $ia_post->instant_article;
    $post_id = $ia_post->get_the_id();
    $video_url = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'video_url', true );
    $instant_article->addChild( Video::create()->withURL($video_url) );
} );
```